# Sticking a TableView Header to the top, causes the header to not "interact" when user scrolls down

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am sticking my `UITableView` header to the top when user scrolls down the `UITableView`.  The header view itself is a `UIButton` which does something when clicked.

The button responds well to touches when `contentOffset` Y is `0`.  However when the user scrolls down, the button still sticks to the top but every touches "passes through" it.

Here is my code to stick the header to the top:

```
  var offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
  var headerContentView: UIView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.subviews[0] as UIView;

  headerContentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: max(0, offsetY), width: headerContentView.bounds.width, height: headerContentView.bounds.height);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be moving the view around yourself, don't use `tableHeaderView` at all.  Instead add it as a subview of the table view directly and keep a reference to it.  Then in `scrollViewDidScroll:` layout the view's Y offset according to `scrollView.contentOffset.y`.

You may need to trigger this layout in `viewDidLoad` so that it appears properly before any scroll events happen.  If the view shouldn't overlap the top cell when the table is scrolled to the top, set the view's height to the table's `contentInset`'s `top`.